# How to display object as a String properly

Tags: java, tostring

Im working on this code and expecting a matrix to be printed but thats what came up
`Matrix@2c78bc3b Matrix@2a8ddc4c`

This is a code example:

```
public class Matrix
{

    public static int rows;
    public static int colms;//columns
    public static int[][] numbers;

    public Matrix(int[][] numbers)
    {

        numbers = new int[rows][colms];

    }


    public static boolean isSquareMatrix(Matrix m)
    {
        //rows = numbers.length;
        //colms = numbers[0].length;

        if(rows == colms)
           return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static Matrix getTranspose(Matrix trans)
    {
       trans = new Matrix(numbers);

        for(int i =0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < colms; j++)
            {
                trans.numbers[i][j] = numbers[j][i];
            }
        }
        return trans;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[][] m1 = new int[][]{{1,4}, {5,3}};
        Matrix Mat = new Matrix(m1);

        System.out.print(Mat);
        System.out.print(getTranspose(Mat));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to implement `toString()` in a meaningful way.

This `toString()` (below) is perhaps suitable for debugging, but will be ugly and confusing if you use it for real user output.  An actual solution would probably use a [`Formatter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) in some complicated way to produce neatly tabular rows and columns.

Some additional recommendations based on your code:

- Suggest not storing the rows/columns sizes separately.  [SSOT / Single Source of Truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Source_of_Truth) or [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Repeat_Yourself), [Java+DRY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898862/variable-value-assignment-operation-duplication).  Just use the `.length`, and provide accessor methods if need be.
- Use `final` in method args, it will eliminate bugs like you have above, aliasing `numbers` incorrectly int the constructor
- Use an instance, not `static`
- Paranoia is the programmer's lifestyle: I also modified my code to do a `deepCopy` of the provided `int[][]` array, otherwise there is reference leakage, and the `Matrix` class would be unable to enforce its own invariants if caller code later modified the `int[][]` they passed in.
- I made my `Matrix` immutable (see `final private numbers[][]`) out of habit.  This is a good practice, unless you come up with a good reason for a mutable implementation (wouldn't be surprising for performance reasons in matrices).

Here's some improved code:

```
public final class Matrix
{
    final private int[][] numbers;

    // note the final, which would find a bug in your cited code above...
    public Matrix(final int[][] numbers)
    {   
        // by enforcing these assumptions / invariants here, you don't need to deal 
        // with checking them in other parts of the code.  This is long enough that you might 
        // factor it out into a private void sanityCheck() method, which could be 
        // applied elsewhere when there are non-trivial mutations of the internal state

        if (numbers == null || numbers.length == 0) 
          throw new NullPointerException("Matrix can't have null contents or zero rows");
        final int columns = numbers[0].length;
        if (columns == 0) 
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Matrix can't have zero columns");
        for (int i =1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
          if (numbers[i] == null) 
             throw new NullPointerException("Matrix can't have null row "+i);
          if (numbers[i].length != columns) 
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Matrix can't have differing row lengths!");
        }
        this.numbers = deepCopy(numbers);
    }

    public boolean isSquareMatrix() { return rowCount() == columnCount(); }
    public int rowCount() { return numbers.length; }
    public int columnCount() {return numbers[0].length; }

    private static int[][] deepCopy(final int[][] source)
    {
       // note we ignore error cases that don't apply because of 
       // invariants in the constructor:
       assert(source != null); assert(source.length != 0);
       assert(source[0] != null); assert(source[0].length != 0);
       int[][] target = new int[source.length][source[0].length];
       for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) 
          target[i] = Arrays.copyOf(source[i],source[i].length);
       return target;
    }

  public Matrix getTranspose()
  {

    int[][] trans = new int[columnCount()][rowCount()];

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount(); i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < columnCount(); j++)
        trans[i][j] = getValue(j, i);
    return new Matrix(trans);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) 
    { 
      for (int j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++) 
        sb.append(' ').append(numbers[i][j]);
      sb.append('\n');
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    final int[][] m1 = new int[][] { { 1, 4 }, { 5, 3 } };
    Matrix mat = new Matrix(m1);
    System.out.print(mat);
    System.out.print(mat.getTranspose());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

for a quick and dirty method:

```
public String toString() {
    return Arrays.deepToString(numbers);
}
```

On an unrelated note, the variables rows, colms, numbers and the methods isSquareMatrix should not be declared as static.  Otherwise, when you get a transpose, you're going to end up with two matrix objects writing to the same class variables.

Comment: +1: Never used `deepToString()` before, but now it's tucked neatly away in the toolbox, thanks!

Comment: Almost every day I see something on SO that I had not realized was hidden away in the voluminous java standard library

Answer (score 2):

You didn't define a `toString` method for your Matrix class, so when you try to print a Matrix you see the result of the default `toString` method which prints the object's class and unique id.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.print(Mat);
```

it will call the toString method of the Matrix class.

So, if you want to print your Matrix, you will have to override toString method

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    // create here a String representation of your matrix
    // ie: String myString = "1 0 0 1\n0 1 1 1\n...";
    return "String representation of my matrix";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To display the `Matrix` class object when you can `print` on it you'll have to define the `toString` method in your class.

Another bug in the code it you are not setting the value of `rows` and `colms`. So when you do

```
numbers = new int[rows][colms];
```

in your constructor, `rows` and `colms` will always have their default value of `0`. You need to fix that. And then you'll have to copy the matrix elements from the parameter `array` to `numbers`.

Comment: as doing that  //rows = numbers.length;
        //colms = numbers[0].length;

Comment: yes, you can do that if all your rows have same number of columns.

Comment: but in this way when i run the program it gives me the following:
java.lang.NullPointerException:null.... any ideas..??

Comment: @WM: Can you update above to show exactly what code is giving you NPE?

Comment: @WM, as pointed out in my answer, you still have a bug in your constructor -- you need `this.numbers = ...` or you're just setting the argument `numbers` to something.  The NPE probably comes from this.

Comment: @WM: You're also coping with some weirdness -- your `getTranspose()` method is referring directly to the static `numbers` rather than the argument.

Comment: @WM: See my answer above for a fully-working, oo'ified version